# Request parameter is not present

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, request

jsp:

```
<FORM action="rotate.action?rt=left" >
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="rotate left">
</FORM>
```

controller:

```
if( request.getParameter("rt") == null ) {
    logger.info("rt=null");
    return "/personszero.action";
}
```

I get in controller: `rt=null` and browser uri is

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/rotate.action?
```

So why request parameter did not pass?

Comment: try
<form action="rotate.action?rt=left">
     <input type="submit" value="rotate left" />
</form>

Comment: Access the form values using FORM scope and the url values via URL scope.

Comment: see the answer @rozerro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit does a `HTTP POST`

which will ignore the query string.

Where as when you are calling it from the Browser it is doing a `HTTP GET`

Maybe add it as a `<input type="hidden" name="rt" value="left">` field